# Ignite Remote Server Thread Not exit, Cause Out Of Memory Finally

Tags: ignite

When I start a remote compute job , call() Or affinityCall(). Remote server will create **6 threads**, and these thread never exit. Just like the VisualVM shows below:

[view VisualVM snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjU2s.png)

thread name from "utility-#153%null%" to "marshaller-cache-#14i%null%", will never be ended. 
If client runs over and over again, the number of threads on server node will be increased rapidly. As a result, server node run out of memory.

How can I close this thread when client closed. 
May be I do not run client in the current way.

Client Code

```
String cacheKey = "jobIds";
String cname = "myCacheName";
ClusterGroup rmts = getIgnite().cluster().forRemotes();
IgniteCache<String, List<String>> cache = getIgnite().getOrCreateCache(cname);
List<String> jobList = cache.get(cacheKey);
Collection<String> res = ignite.compute(rmts).apply(
        new IgniteClosure<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(String word) {
                return word;
            }
        },
        jobList
    );
getIgnite().close();
System.out.println("ignite Closed");

if (res == null) {
    System.out.println("Error: Result is null");
    return;
}

res.forEach(s -> {
    System.out.println(s);
});
System.out.println("Finished!");
```

getIgnite(), get the instance of Ignite.

```
public static Ignite getIgnite() {
    if (ignite == null) {
        System.out.println("RETURN INSTANCE ..........");
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);
        ignite = Ignition.start(confCache);
        ignite.configuration().setDeploymentMode(DeploymentMode.CONTINUOUS);
    }

    return ignite;
}
```

**Server config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
        <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
        -->
        <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
            <property name="peerClassLoadingMissedResourcesCacheSize" value="0"/>
            <property name="publicThreadPoolSize" value="64"/>

            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                            <property name="addresses">
                                <list>
                                    <value>172.22.1.72:47500..47509</value>
                                    <value>172.22.1.100:47500..47509</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>

            <property name="cacheConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                    <property name="memoryMode" value="ONHEAP_TIERED"/>
                    <property name="backups" value="0"/>
                    <property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="0"/>
                    <property name="swapEnabled" value="false"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

These thread pools are static and number of threads in them never depends on load (number of executed operations, jobs, etc.). Having said that, I'm don't think they are the reason of OOME, unless you somehow start a new node within the same JVM for each executed job.

I would also recommend to always reuse the existing node that is already started in a JVM. Starting a new one and closing it for each job is a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks Valentin. It is true that when I start an executed job, it will create a new node withing the same JVM.
At the very beging, I excepted that when I call ignite.close() threads which created by this client could be destroyed. But it seems ignite does`t run on this way.

So I`m going to follow your advise to reuse ignite instance.

Another question is that, Does ignite.close() just finish client node, and close connection with server node. It won`t close executed job on server node.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are created in thread pools, so you may set their size in [IgniteConfiguration](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html): [setUtilityCachePoolSize(int)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setUtilityCachePoolSize(int)) and [setMarshallerCachePoolSize(int)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/mobile/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setMarshallerCachePoolSize(int)) for Ignite 1.5 and [setMarshallerCacheThreadPoolSize(int)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#setMarshallerCacheThreadPoolSize(int)) for Ignite 1.7, and others.

Comment: Currently, the number of threads is not the problem.

The problem is that when client finished, how to finish threads on server
node which created by this client.When client runs over and over again, the number of threads on server node will be increased rapidly. As a result, server node run out of memory.

Comment: I do not actually understand how many threads do you observe on server? Anyway parked thread costs not too much - just stack size, which by default takes around 512k. And number of threads cannot exceed max pool size, that is configurable. Maybe you have large memory usage in your tasks?

Comment: Every time I run a job 6 thread will be created. Server never release these threads. When I run 100 times. 600 threads run on the server. I`ll append my server config after the post

Comment: I cannot reproduce. What version of ignite do you use? Do you run only one node per JVM?

Comment: ignite version 1.7.0#20160801-sha1:383273e3. I just run one node per JVM